# Use of Try...Catch in Visual Basic in Excel 2011 for Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I would like to use Try...Catch blocks in some Visual Basic macros for Excel 2011 on a Mac instead of On Error.  However, it does not seem to recognize those terms.  Is this method of handling exceptions not available on Macs?

Comment: You can simulate a TRY CATCH block in VBA Please see here 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/30991653/4413676

Answer (score 10):

It's not a Mac thing, there is no Try/Catch in VBA. The closest you will get is:

```
Sub Test() 
    On Error Goto Err 

    ' This is your 'Try'

    Exit Sub

Err: 
    ' This is your 'Catch'
End Sub
```